# Update multiple rows based on id in sqlite on android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have db table as follows

[image: sqlite table]

I want to update status column to 1 with id = 1,2,3.

For a single row I can update with content values

```
public void updateJobStatus(int callId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    data.put(AppDBConstants.KEY_JOB_DETAIL_STATUS, 1);
    db.update(AppDBConstants.TABLE_JOB_DETAIL, data, AppDBConstants.KEY_JOB_DETAIL_CALL_ID + "=" + callId, null);
    db.close();
}
```

What to do for multiple rows?

Comment: you can keep condition something like where id<4

Comment: I have to update for multiple id's.  Id's can also be in between like 4,6,10  and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update Your query like this

```
db.update(AppDBConstants.TABLE_JOB_DETAIL, data, AppDBConstants.KEY_JOB_DETAIL_CALL_ID + " IN (?,?,?)", new String[]{"1","2","3"});
```

Comment: I cannot use  IN (?,?,?) coz the number of id's are not fixed

Comment: this ' IN (?,?,?)' create at run time depend on your ids, pass as parameter of method.

Answer (score 3):

I think you current code is working for multiple id but need some of changes as below to achieve your requirement :

```
public void updateJobStatus(int[] callIds) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    if (db != null) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
             for(int id : callIds){
                 ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
                 data.put(AppDBConstants.KEY_JOB_DETAIL_STATUS, 1);
                 db.update(AppDBConstants.TABLE_JOB_DETAIL, data, AppDBConstants.KEY_JOB_DETAIL_CALL_ID + "=" + id, null);
              }
             db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    db.close();
    }
}
```

**Note** : As above you need to pass id array it might be one or multiple.

Comment: I initially thought of having a loop but is it a good approach?

Comment: If you execute many SQL statements, they can be slow unless you wrap them in a single transaction. But there's nothing wrong with that (especially if you have a more complex filter that cannot be implemented with IN).

Comment: So, could you explain whats the benefit of performing this in loop instead single update statement proposed by Vijay.

Answer (score 2):

When you have unknown number of arguments, try this one

```
String args = TextUtils.join(", ", arrayOfIds);

db.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s = true WHERE %s IN (%s);", 
    TABLE_INCOMING_MESSAGES, KEY_MESSAGE_SENT, KEY_ID, args));
```

Comment: There is no `true` in SQLite.

Comment: its just an example